# Upper bound for sum of waves

Tags: fourier-series, upper-lower-bounds

Let the function $f(t)$ be defined as a linear combination of sinusoidal waves, with different amplitudes, frequencies and phases, i.e.

$$f(t) = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \sin \left( \omega_i t + \varphi_i \right)$$

with $a_i >= 0$ and $\omega_i >= 0$. I want to find an upper bound for $f(t)$, as a function of $a_i$, $\omega_i$ and $\varphi_i$. Obviously, my starting point is $\sum a_i$ but I wonder if it can be improved.

**EDIT:** In the event that, in the general case, no better upper bound than $\sum a_i$ can be obtained, I wonder whether such a bound exists for the following situations (independent and/or combined).

1. The case where all phases are zero: $\varphi_i = 0 \quad \forall i \in \left[1, n \right]$
2. The case where the frequencies are strictly increasing: $\omega_j > \omega_i \iff j > i$, and the amplitudes are strictly decreasing: $ a_j < a_i \iff j > i$
3. The case where the frequencies $\omega_i$ are all rational numbers.

Comment: I'm not sure there's much to get out of the second two conditions as there's no inherent ordering in your expression so the ordering of frequencies or amplitude is arbitrary without some additional constraint.  Also, should we be assuming the $a_i$ are positive?  I think any answer will be related to if the frequencies are rational ratios or not.

Comment: Your points are absolutely right. The conditions of amplitude and frequency monotonicity only make sense together. I have edited the question to take everything into account.